# Не доступны ресты при деплое spring-boot application на удаленный tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

У меня есть pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>myApp</groupId>
<artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.boot.version>2.0.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!--Spring-boot dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--In-memory database-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.14.2.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--deploy on remote tomcat-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>io.springfox</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>2.7.0</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>io.springfox</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>2.7.0</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Структура приложения описана ниже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SpringBoot - класс

```
package ...config;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@ComponentScan({"data"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"data.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"data.dao"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

После mvn clean install - получаю war
закидываю его в удаленный tomcat в директорию webapp и стартую.

Не могу достучаться до рестов, ошибка страница не найдена.
Пробовал localhost:8080/имя реста и localhost:8080/myApp/имя реста

Что можно еще попробовать и что я настроил не так?
в списке задеплоенных приложений в томкате localhost:8080/manager мое приложение отображается.

Comment: попробуйте как написано здесь https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy

Comment: Такое впечатление, что  tomcat просто не в курсе про ваши рест ендпоинты

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Благодарю, делал по этому мануалу, но что-то продолбал, не пойму что

Comment: Наследование от класса SpringBootServletInitializer, provided зависимость spring-boot-starter-tomcat

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov да, пробовал добавлять(забыл включить в вопрос) В итоге получил доступ к рестам по localhost:8080/myApp-1.0/имя реста. Но не понимаю, почему добавилась версия, ведь в мавен плагине я ее исключил при сборке.

Comment: То есть сейчас осталось понять, как к war - файлу не приписывать имя версии

Comment: Где вы ее исключили? не могу найти

Comment: <build>
        <finalName>hello-world</finalName> ..</build>

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov оформите пожалуйста как ответ, попробовать добавить аннотацию SpringBootServletInitializer и указать finalName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере есть несколько фатальных недостатков, а именно:

1. Класс `Application` требуется сделать наследником от `SpringBootServletInitializer`
2. В зависимости нужно добавить

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```

   **provided** - здесь важно